# Is It Possible To have A Terraform Variable Reference Either A Resource Or Data Block Depending On A Passed In Var?

Tags: terraform

## Description

I have a Kafka cluster in one Terraform workspace that I want to be created and managed by Terraform and referenced in another workspace.

## What Currently Exists

### main.tf

```
resource "confluent_environment" "env" {
  display_name = var.env_name
}

// cluster type for dev-main and dev-qa => basic
// cluster type for prod => standard
resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-cluster"
  availability = "SINGLE_ZONE"
  cloud        = "AWS"
  region       = "us-east-1"

  dynamic "basic" {
    for_each = var.env_name != "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }
  dynamic "standard" {
    for_each = var.env_name == "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.env.id
  }
}

// 'app-manager' service account is required in this configuration to create topics and create service accounts
resource "confluent_service_account" "app_manager" {
  count = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-app-manager"
  description  = "Service account to manage Kafka cluster"
}

resource "confluent_role_binding" "app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin" {
  count = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  principal   = "User:${confluent_service_account.app_manager.id}"
  role_name   = "CloudClusterAdmin"
  crn_pattern = confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster.rbac_crn
}
```

### prod_data_main.tf

```
data "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.env_name == "prod-data" ? 1 : 0

  display_name = "prod-cluster"
  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.env.id
  }
}

create service accounts
resource "confluent_service_account" "app_manager_prod_data" {
  count = var.env_name == "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-app-manager"
  description  = "Service account to manage Kafka cluster"
}

resource "confluent_role_binding" "app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin_prod_data" {
  count = var.env_name == "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  principal   = "User:${confluent_service_account.app_manager_prod_data.id}"
  role_name   = "CloudClusterAdmin"
  crn_pattern = data.confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster.rbac_crn
}
```

## What Would This Ideally Look Like?

```
locals {
  crn_pattern = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? "confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster.rbac_crn" : "data.confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster.rbac_crn"


} 

resource "confluent_environment" "env" {
  display_name = var.env_name
}

// cluster type for dev-main and dev-qa => basic
// cluster type for prod => standard
resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-cluster"
  availability = "SINGLE_ZONE"
  cloud        = "AWS"
  region       = "us-east-1"

  dynamic "basic" {
    for_each = var.env_name != "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }
  dynamic "standard" {
    for_each = var.env_name == "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }

  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.env.id
  }
}

data "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.env_name == "prod-data" ? 1 : 0

  display_name = "prod-cluster"
  environment {
    id = confluent_environment.env.id
  }
}

// 'app-manager' service account is required in this configuration to create topics and create service accounts
resource "confluent_service_account" "app_manager" {
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-app-manager"
  description  = "Service account to manage Kafka cluster"
}

resource "confluent_role_binding" "app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin" {
  principal   = "User:${confluent_service_account.app_manager.id}"
  role_name   = "CloudClusterAdmin"
  crn_pattern = local.crn_pattern
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: No, it's just an absolute ton of duplication (currently 2000 lines of code) that could be solved if I could have a variable reference either a single resource OR a data declaration. And this duplication is only going to get worse with time.

It also means that we have to change two locations to make a single change which (from experience) is a maintenance risk.

Comment: I mean, you provided lots of code. Which lines, section should any one focus on? Where exactly is your issues? Which variables do you want to use, how, where?

Comment: I would love to be able to write `  crn_pattern = local.crn_pattern`  and have a single declaration for `app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin` instead of two resource declarations for `app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin` one for the cluster resource declaration and one for the cluster data declaration. I have a decent amount of resources I need to point at the cluster (either the data declaration or the resource declaration depending on the workspace) and their children that use the cluster.

Comment: And where would e.g., `confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster.rbac_crn` value come from?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Terraform `try` keyword to solve my core issue. Here's the solution I ended up going with

```
resource "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count        = var.env_name != "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "${var.env_name}-cluster"
  availability = "SINGLE_ZONE"
  cloud        = "AWS"
  region       = "${var.region}"

  dynamic "basic" {
    for_each = var.env_name != "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }
  dynamic "standard" {
    for_each = var.env_name == "prod" ? [1] : []
    content {}
  }

  environment {
    id = try(confluent_environment.env[0].id, data.confluent_environment.env[0].id)
  }
}

data "confluent_kafka_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.env_name == "prod-data" ? 1 : 0
  display_name = "prod-cluster"
  environment {
    id = try(confluent_environment.env[0].id, data.confluent_environment.env[0].id)
  }
}

resource "confluent_role_binding" "app_manager_kafka_cluster_admin" {
  principal   = "User:${confluent_service_account.app_manager.id}"
  role_name   = "CloudClusterAdmin"
  crn_pattern = try(confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster[0].rbac_crn, data.confluent_kafka_cluster.cluster[0].rbac_crn)
}
```